# Sanity check SQL

Tags: sql, tools

Is there any tools/processes to check SQL does not contain any possible issues.

For example we had an SQL ran that forgot to put a `where` clause on an `update` and mistakenly updated the entire table.

Is there a tool that can check your SQL and provides warnings for SQL updates which may be problematic. Or what is best practice to prevent these kinds of errors. We already have a peer review process but still have things like this slip through the cracks.

Comment: Doing your testing on an expendable database would help.

Comment: 3 static code analysis tools that mention SQL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis others exist, search for "sql lint"

Comment: Short answer "any tools 2 check SQL does not contain any possible issues" yes, but it's the actual database itself. To do it any earlier,. you need a Turing machine/quasi-compiler. Is "SELECT * FROM `customers`" valid (with our without the ticks)? It depends - do you have a table named customers?  "forgot to put a where clause " - absolutely undetectable, since for some situations that might actually be valid (e.g. a table with a single column which simply holds a "last modified" timstamp). In any case, this question probably ought to have been posted on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are tools like that and the best thing about them is that:

> **You can have your own custom standards and analysis rules**

This is what you are pretty much looking for here.

So if you guys have a standard procedure through which you go through when code reviewing the SQL code just make your own custom standards and/or analysis rules and you should be able to catch everything you need in real time.

They also have their own predefined analysis rules and standards that you can use or modify if needed.

Most of the tools out there should have these functionalists baked in + more, depending on which one you choose specifically.

Myself I have had experience with [SQL Enlight](http://www.ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/) and it was definitely helpful when trying to keep things consistent across all teams.

One other reason I like SQL Enlight actually is because it is a great refactoring tool for when you come in front of a nasty, legacy SQL code.